Can "either" be replaced by "each"?
I think in the two quotes, either doesn't mean only one of the two options. Since these are product reviews, it makes no sense to say the first option is better than only one of the latter two options. They obviously want to recommend the best option. In the first quote, I think they want to say the round-faced watch seems bigger than each of the other two square watches. The two square watches both seem smaller than the round-faced watch. If so, can "each" be used instead?

Design-wise, the Moto 360 might first surprise because of its size –
it seems bigger than either of the other two smartwatches because of
its circular design, ... (TechCrunch)


For example, the Lumia 900 will net you $100 less than either of the
other two phones. (TechCrunch)


Please check a dictionary. Either cannot mean both. "John and Sally went to school. Either one [John or Sally] could have taken the book". "each" cannot be substituted for "either", which is used when there is a choice between two people or things.

@Lambie, thanks for the comment. But in the first quote, don't they mean the round-faced watch seems bigger than each of the other two square watches. The two square watches both seem smaller.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/354790/both-each-or-either-when-there-can-only-be-two-of-something

If you directly replace the word “either” with “both” you could imply that the round watch was bigger than the other two put together! I think that’s why they use either here. I think “each” sounds clumsy in this context. “Either” is used when there are exactly 2 choices, whereas each would be used for more than 2 choices. HTH

@RobertDavies, that is to say, "either" does mean "each" except that "each" would be used for more than 2 choices?

It may be a little bit more complicated than that, but in this particular case, that is my instinct. Take a look at Lambie’s link above. Generally, Either is a selection of 1 item from many. Each refers to all items in a selection. Both refers to exactly 2 items. I recognise there is some overlap there and it sometimes just seems to be down to common usage to determine what feels right.

@RobertDavies, so if I use "each", it seems like I'm comparing one thing to two things? By using "either", they are comparing one thing to one thing?

I feel like I might be confusing you, sorry about that.

Each. Every single item in the list. Either. An single item from within a list. Both. All items in the list of 2 items.

@RobertDavies, thank you very much. What's wrong with saying the round-faced watch seems bigger than every single item in the list of square watches, except that "either” is used when there are exactly 2 choices?

From these definitions you should see that if the list in question has exactly 2 items, Each and Both could mean the same. The complication arises when used in this particular context. In truth, you would be understood if you used “each” instead of “either” , or even “any”, “either” sounds far more natural to me.

I think the way to understand "either" is to pair it with "or" even if "or" is not used explicitly in the statement.
In your example the implied meaning is: "The Lumia 900 net you $100 less than either alternative phone 1 or alternative phone 2."
In that particular case the meaning is the same as "both", but that does not necessarily mean you can always replace "either" with "both."
For example: "Choose from either option 1 or option 2."
The meaning in that case is you can choose only one of the two options, but not both.
In my experience, the meaning of "either" may require a follow up question for clarity. If someone told me "choose either", it would be natural for me to follow up with the question "can I choose both?" The other person may then answer "no, choose only one" or "yes, you can choose both." But I won't be certain until I ask for clarification.

Thanks for the answer. Can I replace "either" with "each" in those two quotes?

In that particular case, yes. But for the reason I've explained substituting "each" for "either" will not always work. Ex. "Choose from each option 1 or option 2." That means becomes similar to "both." The usual meaning is that "either" sets up choosing only one from two things.

In your example the implied meaning is: "The Lumia 900 will net you $100 less than either of the other two phones" To use both: "The Lumia 900 will net you $100 less than both phone 1 and phone 2."
